# Entity Framework Core navigation properties over-eagerly loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm just starting to play with EF core (using NPGSQL), and have noticed some strange behavior on how navigation properties are being loaded without expressly using an 'include'. An example I'm seeing:

ObjectA

ObjectA->List ObjectB | ObjectA->List ObjectC

ObjectB->List ObjectD

All of the navigation properties are set up, and there are items of each type in the database.

I run a query on ObjectA without any includes, so the nav properties should be empty. That's not the case; depending on the query, sometimes one of them will be filled in without an explicit include (not both, just ObjectB or ObjectC). If I do the explicit include, they both show up, like expected. This is annoying, but not the really bad problem I'm seeing.

Say I query an ObjectC. If I have all the nav properties set up, it loads ObjectA as expected, but now ObjectA also has ALL of its nav properties loaded as well; not just what relates to ObjectC, either. ALL of ObjectA's children (and their children) come back as well. This leads to hundreds of items coming back that have absolutely no relation to what was requested.

This is code-first (I'm creating the DB by hand though since scaffolding in NPGSQL seems very buggy). Here's an example of how the parent relationship is modeled for one of my entities:

```
entity
  .HasOne<User>(c => c.User)
  .WithMany(p => p.Addresses)
  .HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId)
  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
  .HasConstraintName<User, Address>("fk_addresses_user");
```

If I query a single Address, the parent User is pulled back, but under that every single other Address tied to the User as well (this is a single level association, but if Address had any children they would all be pulled back as well).

I'm at a loss right now; the only thing I've been able to do is remove all child nav properties from my model.

Comment: Are the navigation properties defined as `virtual` ?

Comment: IIRC, Entity Framework has a option to enforce lazy loading (or to disable eager loading)

Comment: Can you please post some actual code so we can see what you're doing? Please post your model as well. Also, can you please open issues for any scaffolding bugs you're having? I'm not aware of anything very serious at the moment.

Comment: @FrancisLord You do realize Lazy Loading isn't in the RTM build? Keep in mind this isn't EF 6, but EFC 1.0 https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html#lazy-loading 
To the underlying issue I would say that the relationship is part of the problem but speculation without model code.

Comment: @mvermef I'm sorry, I was not aware of that fact, I wrongly assumed EF 6.0

Comment: I 'think' I see what it's doing now. It's auto including other properties that are already being tracked locally (which makes sense, I guess). My testing I was reading/creating several items at once, and I was confused by some things being filled in without an explicit include. After more testing, it's behaving as I expect when I have simpler queries not accessing other entities in the same context.

Comment: @ShayRojansky Database first seemed to work fine (other than not singularizing entity names, but I know that's not supported yet). I tried code first to have more control, but that failed on table creation. The database was successfully generated, but a serial Id column that the first table was expecting had not been generated yet, so it bailed completely. The generated database was completely empty.

Comment: @MichaelCowart it would be great if you could open an issue on https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL with steps for triggering the scaffolding problem, so I can fix it.

Comment: Also, your comment above explaining what happened probably belongs in an answer to this question...

Comment: @ShayRojansky I'll see if I can recreate the problem in a new database.

Answer (score 0):

I 'think' I see what it's doing now. It's auto including other properties that are already being tracked locally (which makes sense, I guess). My testing I was reading/creating several items at once, and I was confused by some things being filled in without an explicit include. After more testing, it's behaving as I expect when I have simpler queries not accessing other entities in the same context